# "Unable to remove item at non-existing index"

Tags: users, migrations, 9

I am currently working on Drupal 9 build of the Drupal 7 site along with just user migration.

The site had existing 20K users and we're migrating them with Drupal Migrate module with simple bring every user and static map old roles to new roles.

The migration is running well with success of 19K+ migrated without any errors.
However on remaining about 90 users we're getting this error messages:

```
 ------- -------------- ------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Level   Source ID(s)   Destination ID(s)   Message                                                                                                                                        
 ------- -------------- ------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  1       598                                Unable to remove item at non-existing index. (C:\aba-website\public_html\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage.php:811)    
 ------- -------------- ------------------- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And these users are failed and skipped. The error message doesn't make a lot of sense for us as where the issue could be.

Does anyone ever encounter this error message? What could be the possible reason behind this error messages?

Comment: Are there contributed modules installed or any Core patches applied on the Drupal 9 site?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but it was also appearing when you try to save the user. Have you tried editing and saving those users with the error?

In my case we have two multi-value paragraph fields that are being kept in sync with each other (don't ask - before my time). And when those two fields get out of sync e.g. one field has 20 entries and the other has 22, I see that error. I have to manually edit them to have them match, then I'm able to save them and the user works fine after that.

Check if you have some custom that is doing something similar: adding or removing items from a multi-value field on the user profile.